# How do I assign the value in the label to the input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this value from js and i can assign to label, How do I assign the value in the label to the input? Or how i can this value get the from js for to assign to input?

```js
var height = 150;
document.getElementById("heightLabel").innerHTML = height;
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="heightLabel"> height </label>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" id="heightLabel" name="heightLabel" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please remember to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Such as what you've tried so far, what failed, what research you did.

Comment: document.querySelector('.form-control').value = height

Comment: The id values of all elements that have them must be **unique**. You've got two elements with the id "heightLabel".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things:

- `id`'s must be unique. You can not provide the same `id` value for multiple elements on a page. If you need both, a `class` should be used (but that does not apply to your example above).
- To assign to a value of an `<input/>` element, you will need to use [`.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) (or, alternitively, [`.setAttribute('value', height)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)).

```js
// let height = 150; (To create in JS)
// To get label element value
let height = document.getElementById("heightLabel").innerText;

// Ensure it is a number
height = Number(height);
if (isNaN(height)) {
  height = 0;
}
// Set the input value
document.getElementById("heightValue").value = height;
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label id="heightLabel"> 999 </label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <input class="form-control" type="number" id="heightValue" name="heightLabel" value="">
</div>
```